# Is there a way to empty the Web-to-Case / Web-to-Lead queue in Salesforce

Tags: case, limits, queue, web-to-case

We have received a huge amount of Web-To-case request, at some point I received a exceed limit error message debugging the case creation, my question is if there's a way to empty the Web-To-Case queue en salesforce, I mean this because every web-to-case record is sent to this "queue" (so far I don't have idea how to see those records) in any case I'm sure I lost that data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The queue is empty, you've just exceeded your daily limit. Those emails are so that you manually input the leads if you want to. You'll get a new 500 lead limit within 24 hours.